# Windows - How do I undo 'sdelete -c C'?

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-space, sdelete

[`sdelete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) is a tool for secure deletion, and the `-c` flag "cleans free space".

I ran this command `sdelete -c C` on a Windows 10 machine in an attempt to clean up free space on the C drive, but the command fills up that drive.

How do I undo that command and reclaim lost disk space?

Winfetch screenshot:
[image]

Only 90 GB of C drive was occupied before running this command, now it's 469 GB.

Comment: From your own link please read and understand "How SDelete Works" at least from the paragraph starting with *"The second approach, and the one SDelete takes (...)"*

Comment: I didn't realise how destructive the command is when running it, and I do regret it. @ChanganAuto

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run the command to completion. You should be able to find the temporary file(s) it creates and remove them.

Comment: Use WinDirStat to find the huge file(s). Then delete them manually. https://windirstat.net/

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Daniel B suggested, sdelete did not fill up 100% of my C drive.

The OS is still functional and I managed to find the 380GB `SDELTEMP` file and delete it with `remove-item -Force`, and got my disk space back. :)